# DynamoDB scan count is different from actual count of items

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

This is what is shown when I run through each page:

[image]

As you can see here, the list is over 18000 items in the DB.

Now, when I do this:

```
var params = {
  TableName : "theTable"
};

db.scan(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
      console.error(err);
  } else {
      console.log(data);
  }
});
```

It returns me:

> Count: 16633,   ScannedCount: 16633,

Why is it happening? Why is not returning all 30000 items when I run the code?

Comment: You are probably exceeding the max data size limit. DynamoDB just stops and returns what it is able to scan when it ran out of memory. See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html

Answer (score 2):

This happens when your **dataset exceeds 1.0Mb in size**.
DynamoDB returns all the items that together sizes upto a maximum size of 1.0Mb, irrespective of your `Query` or `Scan`.
From AWS DynamoDB DOCS:

> The result set from a Query is limited to 1 MB per call. You can use the LastEvaluatedKey from the query response to retrieve more results.
>
> The result set from a Scan is limited to 1 MB per call. You can use the LastEvaluatedKey from the scan response to retrieve more results.

**NOTE:** These limits are appliable before `FilterExpressions` are applied on the retrieved dataset.

To know more about limits of dynamoDB, follow the document.

**SOLUTION:** If your query or scan results exceeds the limit, a `LastEvaluatedKey` property is also returned in the dataset, you can use it to re run your operation to retrieve the next set of items.